# linearlayout doesn't show all childs

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have problem in this layout that : it doesn't show any child after the listView
and the listview is filling this sight ; it scrolls but didn't show the any other child

I have tried to user ScrollView but it make issues with expandlist

this is layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/select_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="50dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="@string/select"
    android:textColor="#60240a"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@drawable/line_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="3dip"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:src="@drawable/line_divider" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:childDivider="@drawable/line_divider"
    android:divider="@drawable/line_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#60240a" >
</ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `ListView` in the layout you have to add this property          `android:layout_weight` for the listview. Without this property being set, you cannot get all views.

Answer (score 1):

Since your layout is linear any views that exceeds the limit of the screen are not displayed in the screen. Yes scrollview makes issues with list or expandable listview as the scrollview itself is scrollable it will consume the scrolls of listview and expandablelist. To resolve this you have to re order or change your layouts to make your rest of the views visible

Answer (score 0):

Give the first `ListView` some constant height. Like

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dip"
....
/>
```

`LinearLayout` will not scroll when its content increases. And you cannot use a `ScrollView` as parent for `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Set all `layout_height` - attributes from direct childs of your root layout to `fill_parent`.
Than give every of these layouts a attribute `layout_weight`.
The value of layout_weight is an integer according to how many space they've been granted in the view.
For example two views: one with weight 2 and one with weight 1: The weight 1 is twice the size of weight 2.
Just play a little with the weight attribute to find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have given height of listview as wrap_content so it will occupy the all the space in screen so u give the height of listview fixed and same thing applied to expandable list also give fix height to that also.

Hope u get it All The best