# LinearLayout doesn't show all ListView but one child

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have some data which are going to be shown in a `ListView`. The problem is that everything goes well but the ListView or maybe LinearLayout doesn't extend enough to show all children of `CustomListView`; it just shows one child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/LinearLayoutDetails">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ov_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Layout file which contains `ListView` and `LinearLayout`. This layout is included in another `LinearLayout` with `layout_height="match_parent"`. Also the style:

```
<style name="LinearLayoutDetails">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
<style name="SubtitleTextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textSecondary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ValueTextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    </style>
<style name="ViewLine">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0.75dp</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">#BDBDBD</item>
    </style>
```

List item view xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/SubtitleTextView"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            style="@style/ValueTextView"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/ViewLine" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the adapter:

```
package ir.noideaw.aufbau.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import ir.noideaw.aufbau.Model.Unit;
import ir.noideaw.aufbau.R;

/**
 * Created by muhammad on 5/8/18.
 */

public class UnitAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Unit> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public UnitAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Unit> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    public static class ViewHolder{
        TextView name, value;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if (v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit_detail, null);
            viewHolder.name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.value = v.findViewById(R.id.value);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        if (data.size() > 0){
            Unit values = data.get(i);
            viewHolder.name.setText(values.getName());
            viewHolder.value.setText(values.getValue());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

When I manually set the height of either ListView or LinearLayout, the Listview shows more children to fit that height.
Also I have visited many webpages (like [linearlayout doesn't show all childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785570/linearlayout-dosnt-show-all-childs)) to solve that problem but no one responded.

Comment: Where is your Adapter code . Add relevant code in question

Comment: please show the list item layout file!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117195/android-set-listview-height-dynamically

Comment: @ADM just added

Comment: @RishabhSharma just updated

Comment: I prefer solving that by xml if is available.

Comment: show me your SubtitleTextView, ValueTextView, ViewLine style tag of your xml file.

Comment: may be you declared "name" textview width to a "match_parent" in your SubtitleTextView style, if is it then set it to "0sp". or ValueTextView width to a "match_parent", please note that, if you are using weight feature, and whose parents orientation fixed to a horizontal, then its child's views width must be a "0sp" with appropriate weight given to all child.

Comment: @Dhiren just added codes relevantly. no I didn't do that.

Comment: One suggestion why don't you use recycler view instead of listview

Comment: @AndroidTeam I don't know. Maybe because there is only one column.

Comment: Please add "name" and "value" TextViews width to "0sp" as android:layout_width="0sp" inside your original TextView. instead style. and gravity attribute is useless here.

Comment: @Dhiren just added but there's not any changes

Comment: what you did can you please update your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add "name" and "value" TextViews width to "0sp" manually, as `android:layout_width="0sp"` inside your original TextView, instead style.

may be you declared "name" textview width to a "match_parent" in your SubtitleTextView style, if is it then set it to "0sp". or ValueTextView width to a "match_parent",

please note that, if you are using weight feature, and whose parents orientation fixed to a horizontal, then its child's views width must be a "0sp" with appropriate weight given to all child. by applying this your weight feature works well.

Comment: just added but there's not any changes